# How to make a test with selenium-webdriver on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a test with `selenium-webdriver` on my project installed on Ubuntu 20.04

I have installed with `yarn add selenium-webdriver`. Every drivers exists except safaridriver.

I run the command `npx mocha test/**/*.spec.cjs` And everytime I have an error saying :

> The version of safari cannot be detected. Trying with latest driver version

> Error: Unable to obtain browser driver.
> For more information on how to install drivers see
> https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location/. Error: Error executing command for /home/new/projects/projectName/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/bin/linux/selenium-manager with --browser,safari,--output,json: safaridriver not available for download

```js
const { By, Builder, Browser } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const { suite } = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');
const assert = require("assert");



suite(function (env) {
  describe('First script', function () {
    let driver;

    before(async function () {
      driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    });

    after(async () => await driver.quit());

    it('First Selenium script', async function () {
      await driver.get('https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/web/web-form.html');

      let title = await driver.getTitle();
      assert.strictEqual("Web form", title);

      await driver.manage().setTimeouts({ implicit: 500 });

      let textBox = await driver.findElement(By.name('my-text'));
      let submitButton = await driver.findElement(By.css('button'));

      await textBox.sendKeys('Selenium');
      await submitButton.click();

      let message = await driver.findElement(By.id('message'));
      let value = await message.getText();
      assert.strictEqual("Received!", value);
    });
  });
}, { browsers: [Browser.CHROME, Browser.FIREFOX] });
```

Any clue, how to resolve this issue ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using Ubuntu then it's a major red flag to me that Safari pops up in the conversation in any way, because that's a MacOS browser. First I'd try to figure out why Safari is mentioned.
2. Yarn install might not be enough and you possibly need to install native packages, such as `apt install chromium-driver` and possibly even manually install driver from a download (`chromedriver_linux64.zip`) depending on your environment. Once all layers of chrome driver in place the system hopefully finds it and won't look for Safari.
3. Getting Selenium running can be tricky, such as you may need to match version of your Chrome and the Chrome driver, and there are all kinds of "black magic" driver parameters - it'd be too early and long to get into that.